# Security Error when trying to call ActionScript function from JS

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I have a little test swf to test calling an ActionScript(3.0) function from JavaScript. I am using the Flash documentation as a reference:
 (http://www.adobe.ca/livedocs/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000340.html)
 When the page loads I am presented with a Flash Player error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller file: c:/externalinterface.swf cannot access file: c:\myhtml.html
at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_initJS()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/addCallback()
    at externalinterface_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

This is the ActionScript:

```
 import flash.external.ExternalInterface

function callMe(name:String):String{

    return "busy signal";

    }

    ExternalInterface.addCallback("myFunction",callMe);
```

And the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function callSwf() {
        var callResult = flashObject.myFunction("Nick");
        alert(callResult);
    }   

</script>
```

Finally the HTML Object:

```
<object width="550" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="externalinterface.swf">
<embed src="externalinterface.swf" width="550" height="400">
</embed>
</object>
```

How do we work around this?

Comment: in your html do you allow script execution?
params.allowscriptaccess = "always"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you test online or localhost, it should work if you had the param allowscriptaccess="true" like dome said. 
If you are testing with file:// protocol you need to allow your drive in the flash player security options.

Comment: I added the local swf path in my global security settings and the error is gone.

Comment: For anyone else, your global security settings are edited at http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html