# Calling JavaScript function from Flex 4 web application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need to call javascript function from Flash 4 based web application. When I run it in Debug mode it runs perfectly but when I make release build or run same application on other machine it does not call JavaScript function.

For testing I am just calling sample Alert function of JavaScript. Can someone help me what I am missing ?

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="vertical" initialize="application1_initializeHandler(event)"
    verticalAlign="middle"
    backgroundColor="white">

 <mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import mx.controls.Alert;
   import mx.events.FlexEvent;
   public function btnLogin_click():void 
   {
    var s:String;    
    if (ExternalInterface.available) 
    {     
         ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Hello World!"); 
    } 
    else 
    {
     Alert.show("External interface not available");
    }
    trace(s); 
   }

   protected function application1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
   {
    flash.system.Security.allowDomain("always");
   }

  ]]>
 </mx:Script>

 <mx:Form>       
  <mx:FormItem>        
   <mx:Button id="btnLogin" label="Login" click="btnLogin_click()" />        
  </mx:FormItem>       
 </mx:Form>

</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly, make sure JavaScript on your testing machine is turned on and then also make sure you are adding your JavaScript file/code after adding swfobject.js file.

I had similar problem but it worked out when I moved swfobject.js at the top of all js includes.

Comment: Thanks Faheem, I am running both debug/release code on same machine. And Debug mode able to call JavaScript and Release mode not able to call. Actually for testing I am not adding any JS file. Just calling native JavaScript method "alert" with a parameter. But still not running. If someone can reproduce same problem then It will be really helpful.

Comment: Why don't you try the sample code above on some fresh machine that doesn't have debugging tools on it. I have tried your sample code in both release and build mode, working fine.

Comment: I am getting following error :SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller file:///C:/MSAPerMonWebClient/bin-release/MSAPerMonWebClient.swf cannot access file:///C:/MSAPerMonWebClient/bin-release/MSAPerMonWebClient.html.
 at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_initJS()
 at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
 at MSAPerMonWebClient/btnLogin_click()
 at MSAPerMonWebClient/__btnLogin_click()

Comment: Have you tried addCallBack method? Also check - throws - security error 2 solution here http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback()

Comment: Check this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307335/security-error-when-trying-to-call-actionscript-function-from-js

Comment: I tried same release on my mac - non dev env - and got same 2060 error. Added that folder to always allow in Global Security settings and code started working again. Answer that I have posted above explains the logic.

Comment: Finally I got the solution.Setting to run application It’s an one time activity on each system. As of now it’s a work around. Step 1: Run following link: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html Step 2: Click on Edit location >> Click on Add Location. Step 3: Click on “Browse for folder” and select the drive (Example C:\) from where you are running the application. Step 4: Press “Confirm” button. It will show you your selected location.

Comment: And that is only because of file:/// protocol, which should not happen to AIR or Flex applications - You won't need this for deploying on client computers :)

Comment: I can't help thinking this over and over again. Stackoverflow is amazing and you guys are rock!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a test like (Flex):

```
ExternalInterface.call("alertFn");
```

And JS:

```
function alertFn() {
    alert("hello world");
}
```

?

I've never tried an ExternalInterface call to a native JS function like "alert"...

Comment: Well, The code I have written is working in Debug mode. But when I am making release build it not calling JS. Seems like some security issue. Can you guys run above code in Flex 4 builder and validate it ?

Comment: Can anyone one send me working project calling JavaScript function with full code ?

Comment: @FlexJogger, its not the security issue thing. When you release build, your javascript is overwritten by the new HTML wrapper. You need to write your JS again.

Answer (score 0):

After digging out the error code `2060` through

```
Alert.show(e.message)
```

I figured out that for some reason `ExternalInterface.call` doesn't work on a `file://` and needs `http(s)://`

So, anybody who is facing this problem, get your yourself a webserver([Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/)) or a [GAE](https://appengine.google.com) for testing these kinds of things and save yourself from the ["Extreme time wastage"](http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/01/01/securityerror-error-2060-security-sandbox-violation-externalinterface-caller/comment-page-1/#comment-64098):

> I was having endless hours of problems using file:// with the Flex
>   AJAX Bridge.
>
> The AJAX code would fail silently during the SWF initialization
>   callbacks to the AJAX code. I would then have null values for all of
>   the SWF root elements.
>
> As soon as I installed a web server and started using http:// localhost
>   everything worked perfectly.
>
> Extreme time wastage :(

Answer (score 0):

test.mxml
..........

```
     protected function bt1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ExternalInterface.call("callUnity");
        }
```

.js
....

```
 function callflex(){

 alert("got it");
  }
```