# Run function right before the exit of the app [AS3]

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a question. If i have my flash application on a website, is it possible to run a function right before the person closes the website window? Some help would be useful :) thanks in advance.

Comment: I know in AIR you can (there is an event that is fired when the application is closing - `Event.CLOSING` on the `stage.nativeWindow` object (which is only available in air), not sure there is an equivalent in FlashPlayer for the web.  You could possibly use `ExternalInterface` with the javascript `window.onbeforeunload` function to make it work if there isn't a built in event in FlashPlayer

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to catch event when window is closing and invoke a function in actionscript through ExternalInterface.

Check this answer to see how to catch event :

[How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/how-to-capture-the-browser-window-close-event)

Check this to see how to invoke function in AS3 from JS :

[Javascript call AS3 function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161354/javascript-call-as3-function)