# How to create alert popup window in flash CS5.5 Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, alert

I am using flash CS5.5. I want create alert popup window in flash. 
When I publish LMS Meanwhile Google Chrome or Interenet Expoler used so i need to popup message.

This My code:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface; //for invoking JavaScript in 

alert_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnExitHandler);

function btnExitHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    ExternalInterface.call("closeCourseWindow");
}
```

This is my code.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't you debug the process? if any error thrown?

Comment: no error....But my code not work..

Comment: could you post the link if it's on remote server?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to guess what's going on without any error message, but I'll give some tips, that may be causing the problem:

First make sure you allow `ActionScript` to access the `javascript` by setting `allowscriptaccess` with value `always`

```
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"/>
```

If that's not the case make sure method exists `closeCourseWindow` and it does not behave strange.

Always use flash debugger to help you catch and solve the problems easily

To allow `ActionScript` access the `JavaScript` interface on file system, goto: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html
select `Always allow` option, and reload the page where your alert box should work.

Comment: Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL C:\Users\Initech\Desktop\AlertBox.swf
[SWF] C:\Users\Initech\Desktop\AlertBox.swf - 2908 bytes after decompression
Error: Error #2067: The ExternalInterface is not available in this container. ExternalInterface requires Internet Explorer ActiveX, Firefox, Mozilla 1.7.5 and greater, or other browsers that support NPRuntime.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
 at AlertBox_fla::MainTimeline/btnExitHandler()[AlertBox_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:15]
Cannot display source code at this location.

Comment: Thanks  George Garchagudashvili... just i need one popup message that what i gave in browser. so please help that ya..thats all

Comment: have you tried running the script on remote, localhost or with `file://` protocol? that matters, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307335/security-error-when-trying-to-call-actionscript-function-from-js

Comment: Thanks george..but i cant understand that fourm..:(

Comment: I have to alert my popup message in LMS

Comment: i need online popup message

Comment: OK when you run your script in browser look at url does it starts with file://some/path/to/script.html ? or http://localhost... I mean it's better to upload your files on server and test it there, it should work.

Comment: The problem is that ActionScript can't access the javascript interface, and I think this in case security sandbox is causing problem.

Comment: i had to run my swf in interent expoler.but its not work..this is that loaction.C:\Users\Initech\Desktop.alert.html

Comment: Welcome anytime, glad to help you